# MSSQL Issue with Where-In Multi clause

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using two different Database POSTGRE-SQL and MSSQL with  java-hibernate Criteria API. The Sql Translation of Criteria is Like:

`Select * From table t WHERE (t.a, t.b) IN 
               (SELECT   max(this_.a) AS y0_, 
                         this_.b  AS y1_ 
                         FROM  table this_ 
                         GROUP BY this_.id
 )`
 
This Query With Where-In- multi-columns Works fine in PostGre Database But doesnot work with MSSQL .Can Any one suggest me SQL Workaround for multi-column comparion with aggregated function ?

Comment: What does *"does not work"* mean? You haven't posted any error messages. Your Subquery, however, doesn't have `GROUP BY` clause, and is using an aggregate; so I assume the error is telling you the problem. :)

Comment: @Larnu I just posted partial Query.. I have updated now.
'doesnot work mean ' the MSSQL expect only one column in here condition so its give exception 'subquery returns more columns '

Comment: this is why it's important to post all the relevant SQL, and your error message, in your post by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50228805/edit) it. Otherwise people answers are just guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
Select * 
From table t 
inner join (
    SELECT    max(this_.a) AS y0_
            , this_.b  AS y1_ 
    FROM  table this_ 
    Group by this_.b) a on t.a = a.y0_ and t.b = y1_
```

Answer (score 0):

if is varchar

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t 
WHERE (t.a + '-' + t.b) 
IN (SELECT (max(this_.a) + '-' + this_.b)
    FROM  table this_ )
```

if is int

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t 
WHERE (CONVERT(nvarcahr(32), t.a) + '-' + CONVERT(nvarcahr(32), t.b)) 
IN (SELECT (CONVERT(nvarcahr(32), max(this_.a)) + '-' + CONVERT(nvarcahr(32),this_.b))
    FROM  table this_ )
```